# displaying paragraphs not containing a pattern using sed/egrep/awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to separate out paragraphs not containing keywords "VALIDTO" or "DRAFT" , all other paragraphs should be displayed , though we have sed/awk one liners like 
awk -v RS= '/Occurance: 1/' ystdef.txt
sed '/./{H;$!d};x;/SEARCH/!d'

could not find anything for the negation of the same and display paragraphs not containing pattern :

```
SCHEDULE P0015D24#EP_DAILY_1_P
DRAFT
ON RUNCYCLE SIMPLE1 07/31/2004,09/30/2006,02/10/2007
EXCEPT RUNCYCLE CALENDAR2 PEATOFF
PRIORITY 0
:
P0015D24#EP_EA012_BFR

P0015D24#EP_EA012_N
 FOLLOWS EP_EA012_BFR
END

SCHEDULE P0015D24#EP_DAILY_2
ON RUNCYCLE RULE1 VALIDTO 10/02/2013 "FREQ=DAILY"
EXCEPT RUNCYCLE CALENDAR2 PEATOFF
EXCEPT RUNCYCLE CALENDAR3 PTDLY
EXCEPT RUNCYCLE CALENDAR5 TWS85OFF
EXCEPT RUNCYCLE EXCLUDE
  01/20/2007,02/10/2007,03/10/2007,04/21/2007,05/12/2007,06/09/2007,07/21/2007,08/11/2007,
  12/23/2007,12/24/2007,12/31/2007,01/19/2008,02/09/2008,01/01/2009,02/07/2009,05/22/2009,
  05/25/2009,07/02/2009,07/03/2009,07/04/2009,07/05/2009,09/04/2009,09/05/2009,09/07/2009,
  12/24/2009,12/25/2009,01/01/2010,03/20/2010,04/10/2010,09/06/2010,06/11/2011,12/24/2012
AT 0400
CARRYFORWARD
FOLLOWS P0015D24#PEAT_BKUP_CYE.@
FOLLOWS P0015D24#PEAT_BKUP_MNTH.@
FOLLOWS P0015D24#PEAT_BKUP_SAT.@
FOLLOWS P0015D24#PEAT_BKUP_SATNOV.@
FOLLOWS P0015D24#PEAT_RESTR_POST.@
FOLLOWS P0015M00#PEAT_BATCH_DONE.@
FOLLOWS P0015M00#PEAT_REBOOT.@
FOLLOWS P0015D24#PEAT_BKUP_POST.UNRESTRICT_FPR02
FOLLOWS P0015D24#PEAT_BKUP_POST_S.SWITCH_LOG
FOLLOWS P0015D24#PEAT_BKUP_POST_Z.SWITCH_LOG
:
P0015D24#EP_BATCH_DT
END
```

Comment: While it's always nice to see a large chunk of text in a question, it will increase your chances of getting an answer if you tell us what that chunk of text IS - sample input, expected output, something else? If it's input then provide the output and vice-versa. It's also good if you can create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem rather than just posting a large block of text that contains mostly irrelevant lines. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines - that does not describe this problem so sed would be the wrong tool to try to use to solve it. This is a job for awk.

Answer (score 2):

Negating the awk example you provided is simple:

```
awk -v RS= '/VALIDTO|DRAFT/' file
```

is short for

```
awk -v RS= '/VALIDTO|DRAFT/ { print $0 }' file
```

as the default action is to print the record. So this code prints the block of text whenever it matches the regular expression.

Using a logical not `!` does the opposite:

```
awk -v RS= '!/VALIDTO|DRAFT/' file
```

i.e. it prints any blocks of text *not* matching the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v RS= '!/VALIDTO|DRAFT/' file
```